# Super slow ts-loader times when transpileOnly: false?

Tags: typescript, ts-loader

I'm trying to diagnose some slow build speeds.  Here are some quantities that I think are relevant.  I'd like to know if there's a likely explanation and optimization for speeding these up without too much compromise on developers. It's a pnpm `hoist=false` monorepo with multiple typescript v4 projects in dependency relationships.  A tip-most project is webpacked, because of the font, image and style assets that I want to process and bundle as a library.

### tsc --build

```
Types:                80
Instantiations:        0
Memory used:    1324253K
I/O read:          1.71s
I/O write:         0.00s
Parse time:       17.67s
Bind time:         2.93s
Check time:        0.00s
Emit time:         0.00s
Total time:       20.60s

Found 428 errors.
```

### webpack 4 & ts-loader v8.0.14 with `projectReferences: true, onlyCompileBundledFiles: true, declarations: false, transpileOnly: true`

> ~142 seconds, 22MB memory ceiling (according to Windows Task Manager)but, of course, no errors found.

### webpack & ts-loader with `transpileOnly: true`, `sourceMap: false` and no `devtool`.

> Completes in 3.67 hours!  high memory usage

### webpack & ts-loader with `transpileOnly: false`

> ~2 *hours*, 26 *GIGS* memory ceiling (using `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=32768`), finds 428 errors.

There are fewer than 3000 source .tsx? files, but there seem to be over 5000 more .d.ts files processed from node_modules (even though `skipLibCheck: true`). Since it does ultimately finish accurately, it's doing SOMETHING and making progress. I think it's known that webpack sourcemaps can fine you 60%, but I don't think that's all that's happening here.

Obviously there are tons of details and settings that I'm not mentioning, but perhaps you've found a secret that I should be checking out?  Have you found ts-loader have a huge penalty when type-checking compared to a regular tsc build or a ts-loader transpileOnly build?  Any advanced diagnostic techniques I might use to crack this?

Comment: did you try setup build with babel-loader instead of ts-loader it should give you some cache and probably speed up build you may require some separate step for linting/validating types

Comment: Since `tsc --build` is so fast, I'm thinking this is more of a bug in my configuration or the loader which should be fixed, rather than it being a fundemental and unfixable flaw in the loader itself. Caching can come later too, but these stats are ridiculous.  using Sysinternals/Process Explorer I can see that `tsc --build` only reads the 8,000 files necessary, typechecks and does all this consistently in under 30 seconds.  The webpack/ts-loader version file count just keeps rising and rising.  It was at 28,000 reads within a minute before I killed it.

Comment: Did you found the reason?

Comment: I made a little bit of progress here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1245, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42670#issuecomment-781514114 which has been fixed in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43700 and https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/pull/1287 but I haven't been able to fully test yet because of yarn berry patch nonsense for ts pre-releases.  Seems promising though.

Comment: I tested ts@next yesterday, but I didn't saw any improvement. After I have disabled project references it became very fast on a very small monorepo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the exclude field of the resolver to exclude node_modules folders and .d.ts files.

Also take a look at the [projectReferences](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#projectreferences) argument and the [experimentalFileCaching](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#experimentalfilecaching) arguments for ts-loader.

I don't have enough reputation at the moment to make comments; sorry that I'm posting this as an answer! Out of curiosity, how fast is running the typescript compiler on this project taking? I wonder if the slowness has to do with webpack configurations aside from those specifically for ts-loader (ex. source-mapping mode).